# Will the photos keep the same quality once resized? Like microsoft paint or even better?

Tags: photos, image-editing, microsoft-paint

Asking if the quality remains the same from Image Resizer for Windows, in terms of viewing the photos from the original full HD size (via an iPad) to a general 1300 pixel size (in general).

I use Microsoft Paint and still do and do not want to go lower in any quality at all. Unless Microsoft Paint actually made them worse I can't tell!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is your use of the word "quality".

You see *quality* is a subjective thing and depends on your perspective.

By resizing the image you are throwing away data and inferring the what one pixel *should* look like when previously it was represented by two pixels. There is provably less information being used to represent what your eyes are seeing. It is a very definite loss of quality.

The problem is though that whether that loss is acceptable is down to the person viewing it or where you are using the image. Many would not care or be able to tell, a lot of people would, especially if viewed side by side on a high resolution monitor.

"MS Paint" is also not a quality setting. It is a simplistic picture viewer. Other more complete viewers might have higher or lower quality resizing algorithms which achieve better or worse results.

Then there is the question of what format you are saving the resized images as, which is something you didn't mention. JPG is a lossy compression algorithm and *will* lose quality each time a file is opened and re-saved irrespective of whether any changes are made. This is [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). BMP stores every pixel of an image and has no generation loss but is large. Other format compress the image but are still lossless such as PNG.

If all you are doing is *viewing* the images then using an image resizer is a bad move, you should keep images in their original format and state without conversion or resizing and view them in a high quality viewer.

If you have a reason to resize the images, for example to set as a desktop background with particular size, then you quality is once again a matter of what is acceptable to you. Generally though modern operating systems have acceptable resizing algorithms and the original image may well be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer here is: Any resize of images will reduce the quality.

But then; the LEVEL of reduction depends on HOW you do it. Simple tools (e.g. paint) are prone to create artifacts, e.g. rugged edges.
More advanced tools generally add blur instead... which is unavoidable in many cases. Using the "right" tool and then subsequent sharpening of different types may help reduce the blur though.

There are tutorials describing techniques, nothing that is "hard" - assuming that you are acquainted with digital image techniques and why they work as they do.

A good deal of the basics can be learned by reading and understanding the Tutorials at https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers address interpolating or extrapolating pixels as asked in the question.  But I'll add another consideration for completeness.  The term "resizing" is sometimes applied to changing the resolution setting.

A raster image contains a certain number of pixels, which are the actual image content.  The physical size of the image when you print it or embed it in a document depends on how closely you space those pixels (the pixels per inch, or ppi).  Instead of changing the number of pixels and their content, you can adjust the size of the image by changing how tightly you pack the pixels.  For example, say an image contains 1,000 pixels in one direction.  At 100 ppi, the image would occupy 10" in that direction.  At 200 ppi, the image would occupy 5" in that direction.

Some image formats store an intended or assumed resolution (ppi) as part of the image metadata and some formats don't.  If the image format stores a resolution setting, most image software will default to that setting when printing it, and software like office suites will often default to it when embedding the image in a document.

If you want to preserve all of the image content and have the image printed or embedded at a certain size without needing dimensional adjustment, you can use software to change or set the resolution (ppi) in the metadata.  If the image isn't in a format that includes this information, you can resave it in a format that does.  This doesn't affect the image quality except in the following sense:

- If you are saving the resolution setting in a format that uses lossy compression, it will degrade the image in the process (even if you save at less compression than the original image; whatever condition the image is in becomes your starting point, and lossy compression will degrade that).
- If you space the pixels too far apart, like trying to use a small image for a poster, the image can look grainy or blocky.  If you pack the pixels too close together, like using a large image for a thumbnail, the detail can become too small for your eye to distinguish at the desired viewing distance, or your printer or monitor may not be capable of accurately reproducing detail that small.

Also, the question mentions "viewing", so it isn't clear whether you're referring to resizing what you see on the monitor or resizing the image.  If you are just zooming the view of the image, that can affect the quality of what you see due to interpolation or extrapolation of pixels on the screen.  But that doesn't affect the original image in any way.

The same would apply to modifying the image opened in your software as long as you don't save it.  So you can experiment with how an image would look at a different number of pixels.  If you don't save that to the original file, the original image won't be affected.  If you save it to a new file, the new image will be degraded compared to the original.